# Can I access Bitbucket Pipelines environment variables from my source code?

Tags: environment-variables, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, sensitive-data

I have my sensitive data as environment variables in Bitbucket Pipelines, e.g. database credentials. Is there a way I can access these environment variables from my source code? I do not want to push these sensitive data to my repository.

Comment: yeah i mean Bitbucket pipelines.I want to access environment variables in environment.ts file, so once I push the code ng build should access API_HOST and PORT in environtment.ts and build a /dist folder.But i do not want these things in my repo so i am putting them in environment variables.

Answer (score 4):

[Bitbucket Pipelines environment variables](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/environment-variables-794502608.html) are just regular [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). You can access them however you normally would; this depends on the programming language you are using.

For example, in Python you can use [`os.getenv()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv), which lets you optionally provide a default value to use in case the desired environment variable isn't available.

Without knowing more about your technology stack it's impossible to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: but in javascript applications, we get env variables like `process.env.VARIABLE` BUT there it is undefined

Comment: @ZainKhan, what kind of JavaScript applications are you talking about? For server-side Node.js they should be defined. In-browser code, like React or Vue.js, doesn't have access to the server's environment. They require a different strategy.

Comment: yes, I'm using React and here is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71309601/bitbucket-pipelines-not-getting-env-variables

Comment: and also apart from it, I'm also struggling to deploy my Django app to ec2 using bitbucket pipelines, do you have any idea about that?