# Use env variables with BitBucket

Tags: javascript, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Stuck with Bitbucket pipelines.

In my code i have some secret info

```
apiKey: process.env.apiKey,
authDomain: process.env.authDomain
```

But bitbucket pipeline during build can't access them. 

Have set up variables via Bitbucket Env variables UI

In yml file i can access variables via $Variable, but how to do this with code?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I access Bitbucket Pipelines environment variables from my source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917906/can-i-access-bitbucket-pipelines-environment-variables-from-my-source-code)

Comment: Just as a sanity check, add `console.log(process.env)` in your code to check whether the variables are there.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up environment variables in Bitbucket, and access them via $variableName in the YAML build file.

Bitbucket uses the environment variables recorded in Bitbucket when running your build pipeline. But it only does this inside your YAML build file. It won't do anything with environment variables referenced in the rest of your code.

For the rest of your codebase, environment variables are worked out on the hosting server at runtime. So if you use environment variables elsewhere in your code (e.g. in your app.js), you need to configure these in your hosting environment.

Answer (score 0):

This should provide more context for your use case - [bitbucket docummentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/variables-in-pipelines-794502608.html)

- Create the environment variable in your env file
- use `$ENV_NAME` to access your specified variable