# Bitbucket pipelines not getting env variables

Tags: reactjs, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using Bitbucket pipelines to deploy my react app to the s3 bucket, deployments work fine but unfortunately, my `process.env` variables are undefined. I already add my all env variables in deployment variables.

`bitbucket-pipeline.yml`:

```yaml
image: node:14

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - parallel:
        - step:
            name: Build and Test
            caches:
              - node
            script:
              - rm -rf package-lock.json
              - npm install
              - npm rebuild node-sass
              - CI=false npm run build:prod
            artifacts:
              - build/**
        - step:
            name: Security Scan
            script:
              # See more security tools at https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?&category=security
              - pipe: atlassian/git-secrets-scan:0.5.1
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Production
          deployment: Production
          trigger: manual
          clone:
            enabled: false
          script:
            # sync your files to S3
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:1.1.0
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
                LOCAL_PATH: 'build'
```

`build script in package.json`

```json
"build": "env-cmd -f .env.prod react-scripts build",
```

`.env.prod`

```
REACT_APP_BASE_URL=http://myurl/api
```

`App.js`

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'

const App = () => {

    const getData = async () => {
        console.log("base url: ", process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL); // it is undefined
        const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/api/users`);
        console.log("response: ", response)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, [])

    return <h1>My Component</h1>
};
}
```

The problem is when I run `npm run build` locally so the build holds all the env variables from `.env.prod` because the file that file exists in my local machine but in the pipe line I put the all `.env.prod` env variables inside deployment variables but unfortunately all the env variables are `undefined`

Comment: Can you past the error? Also where are you trying to use that variables? Where is your process.env variables and what is this process.env file for?

Comment: in React we keep our environment variables inside the `.env` file.. so when I run `npm run build` (the command to build the application) locally so the `.env` is already there and the build keeps all env variables inside it, but on the bitbucket repo we can't put that .env file so that's why the build is not getting the env variables, and I also put that variables inside deployments variable but that's also not working

Comment: Is your `.env.prod` committed? (I'd argue that it _shouldn't_ be, and that those settings should be injected, e.g. as [deployment variables](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/#Deployment-variables). But if you aren't doing that and you're relying on the file it will need to be in your repo.)

Comment: the file is not committed because it has some secret data as well, but I also put all the variables inside deployment variables as well but still they are undefined.

Comment: @ZainKhan, then the `.env.prod` file you show above is irrelevant. Are you sure you've set the variables with the right scope (e.g. workspace vs. repository vs. deployment)?

Comment: according to the bitbucket docs, we should have put the environment variables inside deployments variables

Comment: it's fixed, I put all variables inside repository variables.

Comment: @Chris can you please also look into that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323101/envrionment-variables-with-dokcer-compose-in-bitbucket-pipelines

Comment: @Chris I just forgot to accept answers because of workload, I will take care next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React runs in the user's web browser and therefore does not have access to environment variables running on the server. They are different environments.

You can [embed environment variables in your app at build time](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/):

> Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with `REACT_APP_`. Any other variables except `NODE_ENV` will be ignored to avoid accidentally [exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/865#issuecomment-252199527). Changing any environment variables will require you to restart the development server if it is running.

The "at build time" part of this is important. To include and use your `REACT_APP_BASE_URL` variable in your app, make sure to define it in a way your "Build and Test" step can see.

Assuming you have defined that variable for the Production deployment environment, make sure to use that environment for the build step:

```yaml
- step:
  name: Build and Test
  # Add this
  deployment: Production
  caches:
    - node
  script:
    - rm -rf package-lock.json
    - npm install
    - npm rebuild node-sass
    - CI=false npm run build:prod
  artifacts:
    - build/**
```

Comment: my all env variables start with REACT_APP_*

Comment: @ZainKhan, `REACT_APP_` does not appear anywhere in your question. Can you give a concrete example? Where and how are you setting these variables?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with the help of Chris I solved it by adding all environment variables inside repository variables

Comment: For React and similar products you need to make sure the variables are available _at build time_. When you moved them to the repository level that made them available to your Build and Test step. Assuming you had them set for the Production deployment, you could also have added `deployment: Production` to your Build and Test step. Now that we've figured this out I'll update my answer.

Comment: yes right, but another issue comes with another pipeline :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323563/error-with-docker-container-in-bitbucket-pipelines