# envrionment variables with dokcer-compose in bitbucket pipelines

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a Django app that is dockerized and I want it to deploy it using bitbucket pipelines, but the error is I use env file in docker-compose.yml which I can't put in my repo, so how can I overcome it.

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: "postgres"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - prod.env

  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/web
    env_file:
      - prod.env
    depends_on:
      - db

  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    build:
      context: ./proxy
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/static

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  static-data:
```

`settings.py`

```py
EMAIL_HOST = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST')
```

`bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```yaml
image: python:3.7.2

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        services:
          - docker
        caches:
          - docker
          - pip
        script:
          - pip install docker-compose
          - docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml up --build
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.2.5
            variables:
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              COMMAND: 'upload'
              APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
              ZIP_FILE: 'application.zip'
              S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
              VERSION_LABEL: 'my-app-2.0.0'
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.2.5
            variables:
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              COMMAND: 'deploy'
              APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
              DEPLOYMENT_GROUP: $DEPLOYMENT_GROUP
              WAIT: 'true'
              S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
              VERSION_LABEL: 'my-app-2.0.0'
              IGNORE_APPLICATION_STOP_FAILURES: 'true'
              FILE_EXISTS_BEHAVIOR: 'OVERWRITE'

definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 3072
```

Comment: Did you try overriding the variable by a shell script at your tasks at `Stages & Tasks`? The second option you have is to use `${bamboo.myvariablename}` approach. You can find it at `Default plan configuration` -> `Variables`

Comment: actually, I just removed my env_file from docker-compose.yml and put them all is repository variables.. but another issue occurs.. issue link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323563/error-with-docker-container-in-bitbucket-pipelines