# error with docker container in bitbucket pipelines

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm deploying my dockerized Django app using bitbucket pipelines but unfortunately, the pipeline already creates two containers but not the last one the error and my files are attached below.

`error`

```
ERROR: for db  Cannot create container for service db: authorization denied by plugin pipelines: -v only supports $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR and its subdirectories
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: "postgres"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/web
    depends_on:
      - db

  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    build:
      context: ./proxy
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/static

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  static-data:
```

`bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```yaml
image: python:3.7.2

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        services:
          - docker
        caches:
          - docker
          - pip
        script:
          - pip install docker-compose
          - docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml up --build
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.2.5
            variables:
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              COMMAND: 'upload'
              APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
              ZIP_FILE: 'application.zip'
              S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
              VERSION_LABEL: 'my-app-2.0.0'
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.2.5
            variables:
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              COMMAND: 'deploy'
              APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
              DEPLOYMENT_GROUP: $DEPLOYMENT_GROUP
              WAIT: 'true'
              S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET
              VERSION_LABEL: 'my-app-2.0.0'
              IGNORE_APPLICATION_STOP_FAILURES: 'true'
              FILE_EXISTS_BEHAVIOR: 'OVERWRITE'

definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 3072
``
```